# Vertical text changes scaling?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I've been looking for some hours for a solution to my problem and I've to admit that I really don't understand how to solve it. I drew a node with vertical text and a line going from this to a box. But when I try to add a line going from the firs one to another box, it doesn't arrive to the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=2em,
        minimum width=4em,
        text width={width("Transformations")+2pt},
        text centered
    }
}

\node (app) at (0,0) {\vvv{APPLICATION}};
\node [rect] (trans) at (8,0) {Transformations};
\draw[->] (app) -- (trans);

\node [rect] (dp_list) at (3.5,1.5) {display list};
\node (in) at (1.8,0) {};
\draw[->] (in) |- (dp_list);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the following result on my computer. I want the two lines to touch in the point (1.8,0).

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answers,
Jean.

Answer (score 3):

Nodes have some default padding around them (I think).

You can use the coordinate directly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original![enter image description here][1]
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=2em,
        minimum width=4em,
        text width={width("Transformations")+2pt},
        text centered
    }
}

\node (app) at (0,0) {\vvv{APPLICATION}};
\node [rect] (trans) at (8,0) {Transformations};
\draw[->] (app) -- (trans);

\node [rect] (dp_list) at (3.5,1.5) {display list};

\draw[->] (1.8,0) |- (dp_list);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As David and Pier noted, empty nodes have automatically inner and outer separation distances, namely, `inner sep` and `outer sep`. For seeing it, add `draw` option to your temporary node `(in)`and you'll see.

There is one special node shape that doesn't have a box and hence any separation installed and that is `coordinate`. It does only have one anchor `center` and when you refer to a coordinate by its alias, it is the only coordinate that is assumed.

Additionally, you can ease the vertical text input via spacing it out.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=1em,draw,align=center] (app) at (0,0) {A P P L I C A T I O N};
\node[draw] (disp) at (3,1) {display};
\node[draw] (t) at (4,-1) {trafo};
\draw[->] (app) -- (2,0) coordinate (a) (a) |- (disp);
\draw[->] (a) |- (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nodes have some "inner space" whether you write something in them or not.

In your case, just draw a line from the center of the node: `in.center`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=2em,
        minimum width=4em,
        text width={width("Transformations")+2pt},
        text centered
    }
}

\node (app) at (0,0) {\vvv{APPLICATION}};
\node [rect] (trans) at (8,0) {Transformations};
\draw[->] (app) -- (trans);

\node [rect] (dp_list) at (3.5,1.5) {display list};
\node (in) at (1.8,0) {};
\draw[->] (in.center) |- (dp_list);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Or you could eliminate the white space from the node changing the `inner sep` option for your node.

```
\node [inner sep=0pt] (in) at (1.8,0) {};
```

and then use your code:

```
\draw[->] (in) |- (dp_list);
```